# Context menu for JointJS shapes

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I draw diagrams using the JointJS library. I want to open a context menu after right-clicks on JointJS shapes. Currently, I am able to capture right clicks on shapes but I don't know how to create the context menu and I couldn't find any sample on the web.

Does anyone have any idea how I can do it?

Thanks,

Azade

Comment: https://plugins.jquery.com/ui-contextmenu/ please read [ask]